# Kibana - Filtros en Dashboard compartido por iframe

Tags: kibana

Estoy compartiendo un dashboard de Kibana 5 a través de un iframe. Dicho iframe lo estoy cargando en mi webapp.

Hay alguna forma de poder setear filtros, limpiarlos o seleccionar el rango de tiempo desde dicho iframe?

PD: Con la ruta puedes seleccionar los filtros y rango de tiempo iniciales, me refiero a algo más interactivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llevo un par de días investigando sobre el tema, la única forma legal de modificar filtros, rango de fechas, etc en iframe embebido en mi aplicación es a traves de la URL. 
Pero eso es un coñazo, ademas, implica tener que añadir un widget extra en mi app para manipular la URL del Iframe... un mierdón.

Por cierto, Kibana utiliza [Rison](https://github.com/Nanonid/rison) para codificar y decodificar esa URL a JS object, lo dejo aquí por si os es util.

Peeero, despues de analizar el JS de Kibana me he dado cuenta de que simplemente están ocultando la barra de filtrados cuando Kibana está en modo embebido, se puede modificar el código de la aplicación para que no lo haga. Para `Kibana 5.4.1` recomiendo que echeis un ojo en */optimize/bundles/kibana.bundle.js*